# How to use Aggregate in Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem with my code and it seems it didn't accept aggregate function inside my select query.  What I am trying to achieve with my `DATEDIFF(MONTH,MIN(LoanDateStart),MAX(LoanPaymentDue))` is that I want to get the total number of months and then use the number of months to calculate with the rest of the query.

I got this error:

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Is there anyway that I could achieve the other way around?

**Query**

```
SELECT 
ISNULL(SUM((CAST(((((lt.InterestRate/100) * lc.LoanAmount) +
 lc.LoanAmount) / ((dbo.fnNumberOfYears(CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), LoanDateStart, 
101), CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), LoanPaymentDue, 101)) * DATEDIFF(MONTH, 
MIN(LoanDateStart),  MAX(LoanPaymentDue)))  * 2)) AS DECIMAL(18,2)))),0)
FROM LoanContract lc 
INNER JOIN LoanType lt ON lt.LoanTypeID = lc.LoanTypeID 
WHERE lc.LoanTypeID = 1 AND lc.EmployeeID = 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT ISNULL( SUM( ( CAST( ( ( ( ( lt.InterestRate / 100 ) *
                                  LoanContract.LoanAmount ) +
                                LoanContract.LoanAmount ) /
                              ( ( dbo.fnNumberOfYears( CONVERT( VARCHAR( 15 ),
                                                                LoanDateStart,
                                                                101 ),
                                                       CONVERT( VARCHAR( 15 ),
                                                                LoanPaymentDue,
                                                                101 ) ) *
                                  monthsDifference ) *
                                2 ) ) AS DECIMAL( 18,
                                                  2 ) ) ) ),
               0 )
FROM ( SELECT LoanContractID AS LoanContractID,
              DATEDIFF( MONTH,
                        MIN( LoanDateStart ),
                        MAX( LoanPaymentDue ) ) AS monthsDifference
       FROM LoanContract
       GROUP BY LoanContractID
     ) AS monthsDifferenceFinder
INNER JOIN LoanContract ON LoanContract.LoanContractID = monthsDifferenceFinder.LoanContractID
INNER JOIN LoanType lt ON lt.LoanTypeID = LoanContract.LoanTypeID
WHERE lc.LoanTypeID = 1
  AND lc.EmployeeID = 5
```

Please note that I have used `LoanContractID` in the place of the primary key for `LoanContract` as you have not stated what that is.

The cause of your problem was that `SUM()` (an aggregate function) was operating on the results of `MIN()` and `MAX()`, themselves aggregate functions.  This confused `SQL-Server`.

I have worked around this problem by writing a subquery that determines the difference between your two values for each `LoanContract`, based on the unique identifier for that `LoanContract` as opposed to the primary key for each record.  (Is your data in 3NF (Third Normal Form)?)

The results of the subquery are then joined to `LoanContract` based on `LoanContractID`, effectively appending each `LoanContract`'s `monthsDifference` value to each record for that `LoanContract`.

`SUM()` is then able to work on a retrieved value rather than having to try to aggregate correctly aggregated values.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: Explanation added to Answer.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation, I am fully understand now why. Thank you so much @toonice

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I fixed the issue right now, I'm using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
ISNULL(SUM((CAST(((((lt.InterestRate/100) * lc.LoanAmount) + lc.LoanAmount) / ((dbo.fnNumberOfYears(CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), LoanDateStart, 101), CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), LoanPaymentDue, 101)) * x.NumberOfMonths)  * 2)) AS DECIMAL(18,2)))),0)
FROM LoanContract lc 
INNER JOIN LoanType lt ON lt.LoanTypeID = lc.LoanTypeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT
lc.LoanTypeID AS 'LoanTypeID',
lc.EmployeeID AS 'EmployeeID', 
(DATEDIFF(MONTH, MIN(LoanDateStart),  MAX(LoanPaymentDue))) AS 'NumberOfMonths'
FROM LoanContract lc 
INNER JOIN LoanType lt ON lt.LoanTypeID = lc.LoanTypeID
GROUP BY lc.EmployeeID, lc.LoanTypeID) x ON x.EmployeeID = lc.EmployeeID AND x.LoanTypeID = lc.LoanTypeID 
WHERE lc.LoanTypeID = 1 AND lc.EmployeeID = 5
```